# Multiple requests to same resource using Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Using the following two calls for identical resource:

```
var p1 = Restangular.one('accounts', 123).one('buildings', 456).get();
var p2 = Restangular.one('accounts', 123).one('buildings', 456).get();
```

Will Restangular send a single GET to the server or two? Is Restangular smart enough to know that there is already a request out to this resource when the second get() is issued?

**Edit:**
Chrome shows only one request go out, but I'm still not sure if this is implemented in Restangular or in the browser?

Comment: what did you see in the networks tab?

Comment: @sza I only see one request, but not sure if that's a feature from Restangular or the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation is seems that Restangular does not implement a feature to limit requests for same resource. The number of requests that go out to the server is dependent on the browser: Chrome only sends out only one GET request, IE 10 sends out two.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a Cache, it'll also work on IE10 as that URL and its response would be cached.